# Why is $x = 25n + 9$ in the equation: $3=(3388997632 x^{23}) \text{ mod } 25$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

Apparently the general solution of this:

$3=(3388997632\cdot x^{23}) \text{ mod }25$

is $x = 25n + 9$, where $n$ is any natural number, it seems?

I get how there is connection with $25$ as modulo, that is: $x =\text{modulo }n + 9$ but can't see where 9 comes from despite being multiple of 3. I am also seeking general solution to these type of equations, as above...or with variables in letters:

$y = (ax^n)\text{ mod }n+2$

Apparently, sometimes but not always the solution for $x$ is just as above: modulo times any number plus some other number? Also it seems that if $ax^n$ is negative there is no easy "general solution" in other words the general solution doesn't apply here as outlined above. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: That big number is $=7\pmod{25}$. By Euler's theorem $x^{20}=x^{\phi(25)}=1\pmod{25}$. That means that your equation is the same as $7x^{3}=3\pmod{25}$. Now, $7*18=1\pmod{25}$, and $3*18=4\pmod{25}$. Therefore, the equation is equivalent to $x^3=4\pmod{25}$. You can easily check that $9^3=4\pmod{25}$.

Comment: @thanks for the edit!

Comment: To *deduce* that $9$ is the only solution, you can solve first $x^3=4=-1\pmod{5}$, which only requires checking $5$ possible remainders. You get that $x=4\pmod{5}$ is the only solution. Then you search for solutions of this form $5k+4$ of the original equation: $(5k+4)^3=4\pmod{25}$. This reduces to $3\cdot5\cdot4^2k+4^3=4\pmod{25}$, which gives $3\cdot 5\cdot 8\cdot k+5=0\pmod{25}$. This has solution $k=1\pmod{5}$. Therefore, the solutions to the original equation are of the form $5k+4$, with $k=5n+1$. This is, the solutions are of the form $5n+9$.

Comment: ok most is clear but just to clarify: you get 7 from Euler's totient theorem?

Comment: The first $7$ was from dividing $3388997632$ by $25$, which of course I made my slave do.

Comment: ok now it makes sense...10x.

Comment: The exponent $23=20+3=\phi(25)+3$ was the one cut down thanks to Euler.

Comment: oh i finally got it...you meant that the result is 7 when you mod the billion number 25, so ( 3388997632 / 25) remainder = 7, anyway. also got the exponent from Euler...

Comment: If your slave isn't handy, note that $100 \equiv 0 \bmod 25$, so you just have to look at the last two digits of $3388997632$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it connects:
$$3\equiv(((33889976\cdot4+1)\cdot25+7)\cdot x^{23}) \pmod{ 25}\implies 3\equiv 2\cdot x^3\pmod 5\\\implies-1\equiv x^3\pmod 5\implies x=5y+4$$ Then applying polynomial remainder theorem, Euler and negative versions to simplify a modular arithmetic fraction, to each case ( we know the base is coprime) we'll see: $$4\equiv 9^{3}\pmod{25}$$ which shows the base to be 9 mod 25.